# python-openid cause segmentation fault on mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to get Facebook login working with Django. I tried Django-allauth and python-social-auth. Both work well with the dev server, but not in production with mod_wsgi.

I get an Apache2 500 error page.

In de logs I have errors like:

```
[Sat Sep 21 15:30:06 2013] [notice] child pid 27293 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

[Sat Sep 21 15:30:04 2013] [error] [client 12.23.34.45] Premature end of script headers: wsgi.py
[Sat Sep 21 15:30:04 2013] [error] [client 12.23.34.45] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

When I remove the python-openid module everythings works as it should (I get the Django 500 error page, saying this module is missing, but no segfault in wsgi)

I use these wsgi directions in my httpd.conf:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess info user=info group=info threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup info
```

On the same server I have many other Django sites in production, all without problem (every site using a virtualenv).

I set loglevel to debug which gave me these extra messages:

```
[Sat Sep 21 15:59:19 2013] [debug] core.c(3126): [client 12.23.34.45] redirected from r->uri = /admin/
[Sat Sep 21 15:59:20 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=28475): Attach interpreter ''.
[Sat Sep 21 15:59:20 2013] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=28475): Create interpreter 'www.mydomein.nl|'.
[Sat Sep 21 15:59:20 2013] [info] [client 12.23.34.45] mod_wsgi (pid=28475, process='info', application='mydomain.nl|'): Loading WSGI script '/home/info/wsgi.py'.
```

(thanks for the edit)

As suggested I change my httpd.conf into:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess info user=info group=info threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup info
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Unfortunately I still have the same problem.

EDIT:

The mod_wsgi docs suggest running GDB to debug. I got some info, but I dont understand the output:

```
#0  0x00007f5aea4db293 in __poll (fds=<value optimized out>, nfds=<value optimized out>, timeout=<value optimized out>)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:87
#1  0x00007f5aeae0b370 in apr_poll (aprset=0x7fffb31f7130, num=1, nsds=0x7fffb31f7178, timeout=<value optimized out>) at poll/unix/poll.c:120
#2  0x00007f5ae501d5af in wsgi_daemon_main (p=0x102e138, daemon=0x1093ec0) at mod_wsgi.c:10801
#3  wsgi_start_process (p=0x102e138, daemon=0x1093ec0) at mod_wsgi.c:11269
#4  0x00007f5ae5020351 in wsgi_manage_process (reason=<value optimized out>, data=0x1093ec0, status=<value optimized out>) at mod_wsgi.c:9761
#5  0x00007f5aeae064a1 in apr_proc_other_child_alert (proc=<value optimized out>, reason=<value optimized out>, status=<value optimized out>)
    at misc/unix/otherchild.c:115
#6  0x00000000004bb50f in ap_mpm_run (_pconf=<value optimized out>, plog=<value optimized out>, s=<value optimized out>) at prefork.c:1073
#7  0x000000000042e2b4 in main (argc=4, argv=0x7fffb31f7588) at main.c:753
```

EDIT2

When backtracing,I saw some expat line comming by. I therefore checked both expat versions:

```
[root@server info]# strings /etc/httpd/lib/libexpat.so.0 | grep expat_
expat_1.95.7


 pyexpat.version_info
(2, 0, 1)
```

Seems my apache install is outdated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why mod_wsgi may crash covered in the FAQ for mod_wsgi.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Apache_Process_Crashes

In particular, you likely are using a C extension module which hasn't been written correctly to work in Python sub interpreters and so it crashes.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

As explained in issues list for mod_wsgi, presuming that it is the only WSGI application running in that mod_wsgi daemon process, force it to run in the main interpreter, using:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question (see above). Unfortunately still the same problem...

Comment: Then use the documented procedure for working out where the crash occurs as a clue. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Debugging_Crashes_With_GDB Also ensure you verified you are now running in the main interpreter. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Sub_Interpreter_Being_Used

Comment: If you have compiled the Python yourself, then rebuild it and tell it to not use the system expat. Option to configure for Python would likely be --without-system-expat. That way it will use a expat version that comes with Python, which is name space prefixed to not clash with any different version Apache may be using. Otherwise you will need to rebuild Apache or install a version which uses the newer expat.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I know were to look for the problem. Perhaps I will use a custom python from within my virtualenv.